# Scorecard Question Part 1 - multiple IFs formula

Tags: excel-formula

my challenge is of 2 parts (2nd part was already responded by Michal Rosa  and Lee Mac).

Here is part 1:
I am working on a scorecard which has series of references. I initially wrote a series of Nested IFs which was very long and also is tedious to change especially when targets change. How can I hardcode or create a formula where I can just change the targets/scoring matrix on the table

Please see sample data:
[KRA Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsdTf.png)

Say if the agent's LOB is Email, and is in a tenure of 61-90 Days, we return corresponding KRA Rating from the KRA Rating Matrix depending on Actual Score. Like for Agent 1, her Actual Closure score is 18.55 and corresponding KRA rating for her tenure of 61-90 Days is 4.

Similarly, for her TPH, her Actual TPH is 7.02, which assigns a KRA Rating of 3 in the Scorecard Rating Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `INDEX / MATCH` :

For the outer one (i.e. the one that will find the rating), you use a `MATCH` which will match the nearest value in the table that is still less than value. You have to modify the look of your rating matrix, instead of putting `4.5 - 5.5`, you have to put a single value, i.e. `4.5`. You always start with the lowest possible value (typical 0 or minus something), and you end with the highest value.

With the inner one, you extract the array (row) from your matrix that matches both criteria (tenure and LOB), and this array will be fed into the outer match. As it is now, you have to use two formula's, one for the TPH and one for the closure. If your KPI would not be in merged cells, but on each row (like for Tenure and LOB), you could add another condition in the inner `MATCH` and do everything with a single formula.

The array formula (ctrl+shift+enter) is like this:
`{=INDEX($C$1:$F$1;MATCH(D9;INDEX($C$2:$F$5;MATCH(1;($A$2:$A$5=$A9)*($B$2:$B$5=B9);0););1))}`

This is a screenshot, starting from `A1` (Tenure) and with the formula in `F9`. I used the colors of your spreadsheet to make it more visual.

[image]

This is the same formula with the cell and range references replaces by text so you can better understand and replace with the correct ranges of your worksheet. I hope it is self-explanatory, otherwise just ask: 
`=INDEX(The_rating;
MATCH(closure-rate_value;
INDEX(Matrix_with_closure-rate_cutoffs;MATCH(1;(LOB_column=LOB_value)*(Tenure_column=Tenure_value);0););1))`

Comment: Hi Peter, I have zero knowledge on INDEX MATCH, but is learning (have used VLookup and IF functions mostly). Are you able to provide a visual?

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO I added a visual, and updated the explanation.

Comment: Getting particularly interested with all of these formula building, etc.... I will continue learning through online tutorials... if you can recommend, would be awesome! :)

Comment: So did the formula work ? I never follow any tutorial, I just use google. But I like https://exceljet.net/ quite a lot. There is some advanced stuff on there.

Comment: I may be missing something, I can't seem to get it right. Can you share the formula with the actual cell numbers using the same data sample so I can follow and replicate, then practice with different data sets from there?

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO If you share the worksheet (or an extract), I can complete with the right formula and send it back to you. Or I can transfer you the little test sheet I made, but this will be same as you see above. There is only one single formula (the one in F9), and the few other numbers are exactly as you see them on the screenshot, but if it would help you, no problem to send.

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO Some common pitfalls with the formula : (1) basic, but depending on your regional settings, you have to replace the semicolon with a comma; (2) it is an array formula, so you need to tap ctrl+shift+enter (3) the match values must be exactly the same (e.g. no additional space after Email or so), best is to write once, and copy/paste in all other cells; (4) the cutoff values in the matrix must be sorted (ascending); (5) if there are multiple rows that match the criteria LOB and Tenure (which should not be the case), the match will find the first occurrence.

Comment: I always use WETransfer. Easy, fast, and you don't need to make an account !

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO https://wetransfer.com/  If you never used it, you can just email the link to yourself, and then copy/paste the link here in the comments or in your question.

Comment: Here goes the link : we.tl/t-t1OVBm7UPE)

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to post a url...please add https:// on the link I sent

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1129647bec27d1d4c6afbe8aec0607ea20181130154313/b3f4a0

Comment: I normally get challenged on columns N-R in the Performance Table tab (specifically on Closure and TPH columns since there are different criteria dependent on LOB and Tenure). I always ended up writing very long nested IF formulas....

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e52171976b6530c7a49dd4dd575245c220181130161340/9271c478988cd3c20430e93e920b01f420181130161340/329472

Comment: I did the formula for Closure. As I wrote in my answer, I have re-done the scoring matrix with cut-off values (not with text as in you file; you always can add a nice visual table elsewhere, even automatically with `CONCAT`). Check the definition of the `MATCH` formula approx. ascending switch (1) to make sure that the cut off values are correctly (and test it !) (e.g. I put 12, but maybe it must be 12.01). On the Performance Table I pasted the original values in Column AA, and I checked in AB whether there is a difference. As you can see, there are a few differences so you have to check why.

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO And as I mentioned in my answer, if you re-structure your table a bit further (get rid of the merged cells, and put the KPI type in each rows), you can use one single formula for your five ratings (columns N to R). You just have to add one additional condition, i.e. add `*('December Targets'!$D$9:$D$13=P$3)`, and also fix the relative/absolute reference to the two other cells (I left them both relative, but you have to keep the columns fixed with $.

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO Hello, dit you receive the file that I have sent back to you ? Did the formula work for you ?

Comment: Hi Peter!!!! This is awesome! Have been able to replicate the formula. Will be referencing this file and continue learning more on INDEX and MATCH functions.

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO You're welcome. Glad it worked for you !